# How can I debugg c code in the terminal inside VSCode?

Tags: c, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I've installed the VSCode in my mac (Big Sur) and I can not run code inside VSC's terminal. I've searched online and I've tried some things but I didn't found any error like mine. Is that supposed that everytime I try to debugg my code it appears like a pop-up asking for permission of my desk's files? ([pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFiHI.png))

It should show the message "Hello World!" and it doesn't do anything.
([Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58nGh.png))

I've tried to put "//" before ""console": "externalTerminal"," because it showed an error but it continues not working. ([Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rFdb.png))

If someone could help me I would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try locating your .exe directly

something like this:

```
 "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\directory\\file.exe"
```

I think this should work